# zip RDDs constructed from different input files

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have two files in HDFS with the same number of lines. Lines from the files corresponds to each other by line number.

```
lines1=sc.textFile('1.txt')  
lines2=sc.textFile('2.txt')
```

My question is how to correctly zip rdd lines1 with lines2?

```
zipped=lines1.zip(lines2)
```

Zip requires the same size of RDDs and the same partitions (as I understood not only partitions count but also equal number of elements in each partition). First requirement is already satisfied.
How to ensure the second one?

Thanks!

Sergey.

Answer (score 1):

In general none of the conditions will be satisfied and `zip` is  not a good tool to perform operation like this. Both number of partitions and number of elements per partition depend not only on a number of lines but also size of the file, size of the individual files and configuration.

`zip` is useful when you connect RDDs which can common ancestor and are not separated by shuffle for example:

```py
parent = sc.parallelize(range(100))
child1 = parent.map(some_func)
child2 = parent.map(other_func)
child1.zip(child2)
```

To merge RDDs by line you can do something like this:

```py
def index_and_sort(rdd):
    def swap(xy):
        x, y = xy
        return y, x
    return rdd.zipWithIndex().map(swap).sortByKey()

index_and_sort(lines1).join(index_and_sort(lines)).values()
```

It should be safe to `zip` after indexing and sorting:

```py
from pyspark import RDD

RDD.zip(*(index_and_sort(rdd).values() for rdd in [lines1, lines2]))
```

but why even bother?

Scala equivalent:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

def indexAndSort(rdd: RDD[String]) = rdd.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).sortByKey()

indexAndSort(lines1).join(indexAndSort(lines2)).values
```

Comment: zero323 - the idea is clear. Thanks!  Why you also use sorting?

Comment: Because I don't want to use `HashPartitioner` on `join`.